# SwiftUI question about .padding view modifier from a lecture I saw

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I was watching a lecture and I saw this:

> Modifiers Remember that viewmodifier functions(like .padding)
> themselves return a View. That view, conceptually anyway, "contains"
> the View it's modifying.
>
> Many of them just pass the size offered to them along(like .font or
> .foregroundColor). But it is possible for a modifier to be involved in
> the layout process itself.
>
> For example the view returned by .padding(10) will offer the view that
> it is modifying a space that that is the same size as it was offered,
> but reduced by 10 points on each side. The view returned by
> .padding(10) would then choose a size for itself which is 10 points
> larger on all sides than the View it is modifying ended up choosing.

I don't fully understand this description because if I have some View I call T and I wanna add padding with T.padding(10) What is this saying will happen because this description doesn't fully make sense to me could someone maybe try to explain it a bit better..? Even though this does seem like a simple explanation to me it doesn't really click.

Edit for screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You've gotten two really comprehensive answers, which is great, but this is not a great SO question. Instead of asking a question about a basic lecture, it would be a lot better for yourself to experiment with the code, and look up resources online about how SwiftUI works. Those are important skills for a developer to have.

Comment: Well the main thing i just don't really understand is the padding thing which experimenting can't really help me understand that. I'm asking how it goes on behind the scenes and what's happening because it doesn't make sense to me to say adding padding will remove 10 on all the sides from the view I just don't get why that is necessary

Comment: I believe this lecture is from [CS193p - Developing Apps for iOS 
2022 Lecture 5: Properties Layout @ViewBuilder](https://youtu.be/ayQl_F_uMS4?si=-IRaRjAH3QlnIlhX&t=3831)

Comment: Do you think it looks like adding 10 points to it, not minus 10, right?

Answer (score 1):

Think about this as calling `.padding(10)` on `T`, creates `T1` view having 10pt larger size at each edge, places `T` at the center of this new `T1` view, and returns new `T1` view.

Thus every modifier can be considered as a factory of new container view which encloses original view and can affect it on purpose.

Comment: I edited the post with a screenshot and I'm still a little confuse here, the first view to be offered space will be the view made by .padding(10)? But isn't padding just a view modifier how could this literally just be it's own view, isn't it supposed to modify an existing view? I don't fully understand this.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provide, the `HStack` is a `View` that is made up of `Card` `View`s.  The `.foregroundColor(Color.orange)` modifier takes the `HStack` `View` and returns a new `View`.  Finally, the `.padding(10)` modifier takes that orange `View` and returns a new `View` adding padding of size 10 on all sides.

This slide is then explaining how the layout works, which is in the reverse direction.  The first `View` in the chain of `View`s to be offered space is the last one, that is the `View` that results from adding padding.  For instance, this `View` might be offered the entire screen if this were the top `View` in the `ContentView`.  The padding view for layout purposes would then subtract 10 from all sides and offer the smaller space to the `.foregroundColor()` modifier.  Since `.foregroundColor()` doesn't affect layout, it would offer this same size to the `HStack` `View`.  The `HStack` would divide the offered space by the number of cards in the `ForEach` and offer this smaller view size to each of the `Card` `View`s.

---

### An Example With Numbers

It might help your understanding to look at an example with real numbers.

Suppose this total view will fit into a space 200 wide by 240 tall, and there are 2 cards in the `HStack`.  How big will each `Card` be?  This is the question Layout is figuring out.

If you have `200` by `240` to work with, then the padding is going to take up space on all sides leaving a space of only `180` by `220` for the `HStack` to lay out its views.  The `HStack` determines that it has 2 views laid out horizontally, so it offers half the space to each of the card views (`90` by `220`).

So, the padding is actually going to make the `Card` `View`s smaller because it is taking up some of the existing space.

---

### Example to Play With in an iOS App

Try the following code in an iOS app.  Run it as is and see what it looks like.  Then change the padding to `100` and run it again.  Notice that as the padding gets larger, the red and blue views get smaller.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Color.red
            Color.blue
        }
        .padding(10)
    }
}
```

---

### More Extensive Example with Slider to Adjust Padding

Here is a interactive example that shows the padding in `Color.green` that can be adjusted with the slider.  The dimensions of the red and blue views are shown using `GeometryReader`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var pad: CGFloat = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    ZStack {
                        Color.red
                        Text("\(geo.size.width, specifier: "%.1f")x\(geo.size.height, specifier: "%.1f")").foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    ZStack {
                        Color.blue
                        Text("\(geo.size.width, specifier: "%.1f")x\(geo.size.height, specifier: "%.1f")").foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            }
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .padding(pad)
        }
        .background(Color.green)
        HStack {
            Text("Padding =")
            HStack {
                Text("\(pad, specifier: "%.1f")")
                Spacer()
            }.frame(width: 50)
        }.foregroundColor(.green)
        Slider(value: $pad, in: 0...100).padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Comment: I honestly still don't understand why the padding view subtracts 10 from all sides and offers that smaller space to the .foregroundColor() modifier? If it's subtracting 10 won't that just make the view smaller than it's supposed to be?

Comment: How big is the view "supposed to be"?  That is for Layout to determine.  By specifying `.padding(10)` you are saying that you want 10 pixels of padding to be on all side of the `HStack` view containing the cards.  Layout says "OK, to add that padding I am going to make the `HStack` view smaller so that everything still fits on the screen.

Comment: Well if I do something like Text("Hello") and then do Text("Hello).padding(50) will it make the second View smaller as well? Because I tested this in playgrounds and both of these Views seem to be the exact same size.

Comment: It will only make the Text view smaller if it is constrained.  50 isn't enough and the padded view will fit on screen.  If you increase the size of the padding, eventually it will be necessary to shrink the Text view in order to make the padding fit.

Comment: Try this in your Playground: `VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
            Text("Hello World").padding(30)
        }.frame(width: 100)`